# how to build a customized terminal for linux

Tags: python, gtk, ncurses, curses, vte

I need to build a terminal that looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFGCK.png

the rule is always the same column indicate the numbers and letters ABC are your input.
is possible to do with ncurses or gtk-vte?
any suggestions?

so far i got this:

```
import gtk
import vte

window = gtk.Window()
window.set_title("EDAL")
window.fullscreen()

scroll = gtk.ScrolledWindow()

shell = vte.Terminal()
shell.connect("child-exited", gtk.main_quit)
shell.fork_command()

scroll.add(shell)

window.add(scroll)

window.connect('delete-event', gtk.main_quit)
window.show_all()

gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need a monospaced font.

```
import pango

# Insert this code between "shell.connect..." and "shell.fork_command..."
font = pango.FontDescription()
font.set_family("Ubuntu Mono")
font.set_size(11 * pango.SCALE)
font.set_weight(pango.WEIGHT_NORMAL)
font.set_stretch(pango.STRETCH_NORMAL)
shell.set_font_full(font, True)
```